# Why can I have an index on a non-existing field?

Tags: sqlite

A project that I'm working on uses an SQLite database and a create-script that has the following line:

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_Certificates_Unique" ON "Certificates" ("Usage","PortalUsersID")
```

Strangely enough, this works just fine and the created database really has this index. (Which I know as I retrieved this code from the DB itself by querying the pragma_index_info() for this table.
The strange thing is that table "Certificates" does have a field "Usage" but the field "PortalUsersID" *does not exist!!!* Yet, there's an index on it. Somehow.
I don't believe in *magic* so I would like an explanation about why this is possible in SQLite. And how can I check for other invalid indices? Is it even invalid?
Should I consider this a bug in SQLite or is it a weird feature?

Now, to show the problem, I've tested the following with a clean, in-memory database. I use the DB Browser for SQLite and just one SQL script with four statements:

```
CREATE TABLE "Certificates" (
  "CertificatesID" VARCHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY, 
  "Usage" VARCHAR(1), 
  "UsersID" VARCHAR(36), 
  "Created" TIMESTAMP, 
  "Description" VARCHAR(75), 
  "Payload" BLOB);
CREATE INDEX "idx_Certficates_Created" ON "Certificates" ("Created");
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "idx_Certificates_PK" ON "Certificates" ("CertificatesID");
CREATE INDEX "idx_Certificates_Unique" ON "Certificates" ("Usage","PortalUsersID");
```

Somehow, this works[image]

Comment: Trying to create an index using a column that doesn't exist gives me an error.

Comment: Creating an index with non-existing column also fails for me, except this database shows me this SQL script that shows it exists. I'll expand the question with a second script that works for me, though...

Comment: Oh! I see what the problem is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL, double quotes are used to quote identifiers like column and table names. SQLite uses that too, but, in a retrospectively bad attempt at MySQL compatibility, also [treats double quoted things as string literals](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#double_quoted_string_literals_are_accepted) (Normally single quotes are used for these). If a double quoted value *isn't* the name of a table or relevant column, it's treated as a string.

Indexes can be on [expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html), not just columns. And a string literal is an expression. So your index is on the `Usage` column and the *string* `'PortalUsersID'` (Which is the same for every row in the index).

Recent versions of SQLite can disable this double quote behavior using the C API (See first link). Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a pragma that can be used to do it when you don't have access to low level configuration routines.

Comment: :O O.M.G. It's not a bug! It's a feature! That's a proper explanation and just means detecting these bad indices. This query `select s."name" as "Index", s.tbl_name as "Table", s.sql as "Sql" from sqlite_schema as s join pragma_index_xinfo(s.name) as p where p.cid=-2` seems to find these faulty indices, apparently.